# JavaFx application with firebase realtime database not working

Tags: java, firebase, intellij-idea, javafx, java-8

My Application works fine in IntelliJ-IDEA

Using artifact, I created a .EXE file which loades the classes but doesn't connect with Firebase. SignIn and Up functionalities works fine while running through IDE, but when running from .EXE file it's not working 
as if there is no functionality defined.

**Firebase Connection**
[image: Firebase Connection]

**calling connection request**
[image: calling connection request]

**Functionality**
[image: Functionality]

FirebaseController:

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

    public class FirebaseController {
        static Firestore openConnection(){
            InputStream serviceAccount;
            GoogleCredentials credentials = null;
            try {
                serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("firebase-adminsdk.json");
            credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FirebaseOptions options = null;
        if (credentials != null) {
            options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(credentials)
                    .build();
        }
        assert options != null;
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        return FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
    }
    private static Firestore db = FirebaseController.openConnection();
    public static Firestore ShareDB() {
        return db;
    }
}
```

Calling the method ShareDB():

```
db1 = FirebaseController.ShareDB();
```

Functionality(On Signin button clicked):

```
CollectionReference colRef = db1.collection("users").document(UID).collection(ufire);
DocumentReference docRef = colRef.document("Account");

ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future = docRef.get();
DocumentSnapshot document = future.get();
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions (check your logs)?? And [please don't post images of code (or errors)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6395627).

Comment: No errors, code works fine when run from IDE. it doesn't communicate when deployed to .exe .

Comment: found why it's not working,

Comment: the service account key file serviceAccount.json isn't getting packed

Comment: here is the exception:https://pastebin.com/TTbGtDZv